# Help needed:Analyze the dump file in WinDbg

Tags: crash-dumps

I failed to analyze the dump file using Windbg.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here are my WinDbg settings:
Symbol Path: C:\symbols;srv*c:\mss*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
(C:\symbols contains my own exe and dll symbols, map,pdb etc etc)
Image Path: C:\symbols
Source Path: W:\

## loading crash dump(second chance) shows:

> WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for nbsm.dll GetPageUrlData failed,
>   server returned HTTP status 404 URL requested:
>   http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/nbsm_sm_exe/8_0_0_0/4e5649f3/KERNELBASE_dll/6_1_7600_16385/4a5bdbdf/e06d7363/0000b727.htm?Retriage=1
>
> FAULTING_IP: 
>   +3a22faf00cadf58 00000000 ??              ???
>
> EXCEPTION_RECORD:  `fffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)`
>   ExceptionAddress: `000000007507b727
>   (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x0000000000000058)`    ExceptionCode:
>   `e06d7363` (C++ EH exception)   ExceptionFlags: `00000009`
>   NumberParameters: 3
>
> ```
>   Parameter[0]: 0000000019930520
>
>    Parameter[1]: `0000000001aafb10`
>    Parameter[2]: 000000000040c958
> ```
>
> DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  STACKIMMUNE
>
> PROCESS_NAME:  nbsm_sm.exe
>
> ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) `0xe06d7363` -
>
> EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) `0xe06d7363` -
>
> EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  `0000000019930520`
>
> EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  `0000000001aafb10`
>
> EXCEPTION_PARAMETER3:  `000000000040c958`
>
> MOD_LIST:
>
> NTGLOBALFLAG:  0
>
> APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0
>
> ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute
>   [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from `Frame:[0]` on
>   thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]
>
> LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from `000000007324dbf9` to `000000007507b727`
>
> FAULTING_THREAD:  `ffffffffffffffff`
>
> PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  STACKIMMUNE
>
> BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_STACKIMMUNE_ZEROED_STACK
>
> STACK_TEXT:   `00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000` nbsm_sm.exe+`0x0`
>
> STACK_COMMAND:  `.cxr 01AAF6E8 ; kb ; ** Pseudo Context ** ; kb`
>
> SYMBOL_NAME:  nbsm_sm.exe
>
> FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner
>
> MODULE_NAME: nbsm_sm
>
> IMAGE_NAME:  nbsm_sm.exe
>
> DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  `4e5649f3`
>
> FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  `STACKIMMUNE_e06d7363_nbsm_sm.exe!Unknown`
>
> BUCKET_ID: 
>   `X64_APPLICATION_FAULT_STACKIMMUNE_ZEROED_STACK_nbsm_sm.exe`
>
> FOLLOWUP_IP:  nbsm_sm!__ImageBase+0
>
> ```
> 00400000 4d              dec     ebp
> ```
>
> WATSON_STAGEONE_URL: 
>   http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/nbsm_sm_exe/8_0_0_0/4e5649f3/KERNELBASE_dll/6_1_7600_16385/4a5bdbdf/e06d7363/0000b727.htm?Retriage=1

========================

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!
Sandeep

Comment: Do you know why FAULTY_IP and ExceptionAddress field differ?

Answer (score 1):

If this crash dump has come from a user and it is either reproducible on their system or happens relatively often then you could ask them to download [procdump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) and run a command such as this:

```
procdump -e 1 -w nbsm_sm.exe c:\dumpfiles
```

This will create a dumpfile on the first chance exception which may give you more useful information than you have at the moment.  Sometimes the dump from a second chance exception is just produced too late to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run 'kb' in WinDbg to see the actual stack trace. If you don't see any valuable information, assuming you are developing a native/managed C++ application, you can turn on stack checks (/GS on the cl command line)  and re-run the program.